# TLS Contact Scanned documents for Student Schengen Visa

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, france, applications, student-visas

As a student at what point do I scan and upload supporting documents for a Schengen visa to France?

The issue is that after booking my appointment successfully and paying my service fees online, I noticed I need to upload scanned copies of my supporting documents.

Comment: According to this https://mail/web/france-visas/numerisation submitting dicuments digitally is an *option* Why is it an issue?

Comment: @Traveller your link is broken.

Comment: @JakeDot Ok well try searching for the official site france-visas.gouv.fr Pretty easy to find

Comment: just appending your link fragment to that site name gives me a 404 too. but https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/numerisation works.